# I have some issues with my code using json with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to call json data by using an ajax jquery but it's having some issues and i am new in json with ajax. Anybody, please locate the problem?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Striped Rows</h2>
    <p>The .table-striped class adds zebra-stripes to a table:</p>
    <div align="center">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Details">
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
    <br />
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#search').keyup(function () {
        $('#result').html('');
        var searchField = $('#search').val();
        var expression = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');
        $.getJSON('data.json', function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                if (value.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.location.search(expression) != -1) {
                    $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item"><span class="muted">'+value.userId+'</span> | <span class="text-muted">'+value.id+'</span> | <span class="text-muted">'+value.title+'</span> | <span class="text-muted">'+value.body+'</span></li>')
                }
            });
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: It would be great if you could get more specific about those "some issues" - how are we supposed to help otherwise? Please state your desired result and in which way it is failing. And if you're getting any errors in the console, please include them in the question as well.

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Abubakar%20Noor/Desktop/test/data.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Well, the error message states it quite clearly: You can't make an Ajax request to a local file. Your page and the data.json should be located on a local or live http server.

Comment: Here's an adapted example showing that your code itself runs fine actually: https://codepen.io/pen/ (try

Comment: Due to security permissions you cant able to access local file on client side until the file was on server path

Comment: file is inside local folder